# On group view click listener not working for changing views

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Basically I was trying to change the Image on the group click and its not successful.

I am able to receive correct logs for group expanded and collapsed but the ImageView is not updating according to that.

Here's a sample code for it and I am not sure what's wrong with it:

```
private android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener mGroupClickListener= new OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

            Bitmap mBitmapCollapsed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Bitmap mBitmapExpanded = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_drawer);

            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.carat_imageView);

            if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {

                parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
                Log.d("onGroupClick:", "groupCollapsed");
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmapCollapsed);

            } else {

               parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
               Log.d("onGroupClick:", "groupExpanded");
               mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmapExpanded);

            }

            return false;
        }
    };
```

I am not able to determine the problem here and it seems like the code is fine.

A little help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Found a solution actually:**

**onGroupView:**

I set the id as :

```
//isExpanded is a boolean in the onGroupView method

(!isExpanded) ? R.drawable.closed_icon: R.drawable.expanded_icon;
```

and set the ImageView as :

```
mImageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Hope this helps someone..:)

Comment: This is a possible solution I found and its working fine now.. this may help others as well. Thanks anyways ..:)

Not going to close this post if there are other possible solutions as well.